# android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-framelayout

I don't see any errors and the debug is not very useful. How can I fix that error?

This is part of the code and the error appears inside the last line

Thanks in advance!

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selfie_list);

        mMatrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id","_data","_details"});

        ListView lVThumbnail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.selfie_list_layout);

        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getBaseContext(),
                R.layout.activity_selfie_list,
                null,
                new String[] { "_data","_details"} ,
                new int[] { R.id.img_thumbnail,R.id.tv_details},
                0
               );

        lVThumbnail.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And this are the layouts used, the first one is the list fragment (since I use a list and detailed fragments), and the second is the list layout. :

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/selfie_list"
android:name="com.lordpato.dailyselfie.SelfieListFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
tools:context="com.lordpato.dailyselfie.SelfieListActivity"
tools:layout="@layout/lv_layout" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/selfie_list_layout"
android:layout_height="75dp" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_thumbnail"
    android:padding="5dp"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Please consider an upvote and/or acceptance if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**selfie_list_layout** is not a ListView.

```
ListView lVThumbnail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.selfie_list_layout);
```

...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/selfie_list_layout"
    android:layout_height="75dp" >
```

Comment: I got same issue, thanks to Powell's answer,  for above question, I think simply modify